# Blackberry Facebook NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: facebook, exception, blackberry

I'm probably doing something dumb but my attempts to access the BB Facebook functionality are failing. Here's the code (taken straight from the FB sample code provided):

```
 String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
 String APPLICATION_ID = "app_id here";
 String APPLICATION_SECRET = "secret_key here";
 String[] PERMISSIONS = Facebook.Permissions.USER_DATA_PERMISSIONS;

 ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);
 Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);
```

It falls over on the Facebook fb ... line.

Any pointers anyone?

Comment: Whats failing? whats happening?

Comment: it raises a NoClassDefFoundError exception

Comment: Which device are you testing in. what os?

Comment: The BB Simulator runing 7.1.0 on a 9900

Answer (score 0):

Grab all of the source - don't change any package names - and drop the trunk on a BB project.

Compile and run - it's a namespace problem.

It's a mistake to trust the suggested jar.