# Blackberry Facebook SDK throwing exception: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: facebook, eclipse, blackberry, noclassdeffounderror

I've searched through all the topics related to my question but couldn't find a solution to it.
I'm coding for a Blackberry app using the BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse v1.5.2 with JRE 7.1.0. I'm currently trying to integrate Facebook Connect into my app so that the users can log into our app through Facebook.
The Blackberry Facebook SDK that I'm using is version 0.8.25 downloaded from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/

After getting the two jar files, FacebookBlackberrySDK-v0.8.25.jar and Log4B-v0.9.4.jar I first preverified them with eclipse successfully and included them into my project as libraries.
The project compiled successfully but then I got a run time error: `NoClassDefFoundError`.
After debugging, I found out that the exception was thrown at this line:

```java
fb = Facebook.getInstance(new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, Facebook.Permissions.ALL_PERMISSIONS));
```

and I suspect that the program couldn't find the file Facebook.class
below is my source code:

```java
package com.nextmobile.ecourage.net;

import com.blackberry.facebook.ApplicationSettings;
import com.blackberry.facebook.Facebook;

public class FacebookLogin
{
    private final String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
    private final String APPLICATION_ID = "153555168010272";
    private final String APPLICATION_SECRET = "354f91a79c8fe5a8de9d65b55ef9aa1b";
    private Facebook fb;
    private Facebook fb4u;

    public FacebookLogin()
    {
        fb = Facebook.getInstance(new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, Facebook.Permissions.ALL_PERMISSIONS));
        fb4u = Facebook.getInstance(new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, Facebook.Permissions.USER_DATA_PERMISSIONS));
        fb4u.addPermission(Facebook.Permissions.OFFLINE_ACCESS);
    }
}
```

So I replaced those lines with only this line of code:

```java
new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, Facebook.Permissions.ALL_PERMISSIONS);
```

and it worked without giving any error.
It's weird cause both Facebook.class and ApplicationSettings.class were in the same directory and the program could find ApplicationSettings.class but not Facebook.class.

both classes are under the package: `com.blackberry.facebook`

Does anyone have any idea on this? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882973/blackberry-facebook-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: I've seen that but the question was not resolved. I couldn't find any solution to this.

Comment: the answer from Defi (he also asked the question itself) is correct I think

Comment: Hey @Eugen. The answer says "Grab all of the source - don't change any package names - and drop the trunk on a BB project." I don't quite understand that. I only have the 2 .jar files. Could you clarify on that maybe? Thank you :)

Comment: Checkout library sources, put them into your project src folder and compile into project without changes

Comment: Hey Eugen. So I tried what you said. By checking out the library sources and adding them into the project directly. Another problem arose. It gave me this error "Error: Cannot run program "jar": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified" After researching for a bit, some people say that it's caused by having more than 100 compiled classes in the project. I checked it out and found that by adding the source files directly, it did give me more than 100 compiled classes indeed. Do you have any thoughts on this? Thank you

Comment: Did anyone get the solution? I am facing this classnotfounderror from last 5 days and still couldn't get the solution. I am facing same error while clicking on share button. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Java SDK, you should check out this sample provided by RIM on integrating facebook & twitter into your BB apps: https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/tree/master/SocialApp

Comment: I tried out the sample and it only displayed a blank page titled "My Title" and didn't do anything else.
The code that I used in my app was also taken from the strawberry sample. So I think it should work cause many people have used it before.

Comment: Okay I got SocialApp running but there were only two buttons: "Photo Share" and "Text Share". When I clicked on text share, only a dialog "Let's be social!" appeared and nothing happened after that. While for  Photo Share, it directed me to choose a picture and after choosing one, same nothing happened.

I'm wondering for the blackberry facebook sdk in my code, might it be the problem with code signing key?

Comment: But since I'm running it on a simulator, code signing shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Be careful because it's solution only for 7.0+ OS

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason ApplicationSettings is compiled with higher java version.
Check your project properties->java compiler->compiler compliance level -> this must be 1.4